# Ubuntu Phone Aquaris 4.5 today screen does not automatically change

Tags: ubuntu-touch, scopes

I have a new Ubuntu Aquaris E4.5 phone (latest updates installed).  Locale UK Timzone British Summer Time.

The Today Scope screen does not automatically change days, so for example today is Thursday, but this morning is was still showing Wednesday.  The only way I could seem to get it to change was to reboot the phone.

Is this a bug? or have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is indeed a reported bug.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/today-scope/+bug/1439382

Answer (score 1):

Just type some words in search box and then the date will be up to date. I think it's a kind of bug to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other scopes, you have to swipe it to bottom to refresh the datas

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can do it the console way. Install `terminal` application, log into `terminal`. Type `sudo su -`. Now, you have to remount the the filesystem with with `rw` enabled: `mount -o rw,remount /`. I don't remember if I had `ntp` installed. Now run `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`, choose your location and it should be OK now. You may also need to go to `System settings`, then go to `Time & date` and set up the clock to `Manually`. Your phone should be able to choose any timezone you want. I had to do it this way.