# Wrong date is shown

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone, date

On my ubuntu phone the date is not shown correct, it always shows the yesterday's date,I have to restart the device and then it works and my settings are on automatically, why this ?

Comment: This was confirmed as a bug a couple of days ago https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-image/+bug/1434783

Comment: same issue http://askubuntu.com/questions/607222/ubuntu-phone-aquaris-4-5-today-screen-does-not-automatically-change